# How to assign code from a function to a button?

Tags: excel, vba

How do I call this function with the click of a button.
Is there a way to assign this function to a button?

```vb
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Within your button code, put `Dim path As String`, `path = GetFolder`?

Comment: Basically, you can't assign a `Function` to a button, only a `Sub. The function you have let the user select a folder and return that folder name. Before we can help you, you need to explain what you want to do with that folder.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click button then go to **"Assign Macro"** option, select the **Sub** that you want to call on click on that button, and click "**OK**"

You can not assign the **function** to the button so you need to create a **Sub**, you can create the sub like this:

```
Sub ClickBottonSub()
    Dim GetFolderPath As String
    GetFolderPath = GetFolder
End Sub
```

Comment: which leads to the question I asked in the comment: What is the purpose? Now you can click on the button, select a folder and nothing happens with that - the result disappears in the big data nirvana.

Comment: Maybe `MsgBox GetFolderPath` will do what he wants?

Comment: Thanks guys. Poonam answered my question. Thanks Poonam. Also, my purpose is to access a specific folder path of my choice which I would want to access on a regular basis to access files within the file folder path. How do I key in the file folder path permanently within this code? Doesn't have to be this same code or doesn't have to be function.